# Update Trigger better approach

Tags: t-sql, triggers, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a Trigger i am developing and want it to basically handle Updates in the sense of the `Update` statement, not so worried about `Delete` or `Insert` statements at the moment.

The end result is that i have two status fields `active` & `inactive`, which are `bit` & `datetime` respectively.  The `active` field is used to invalidate a record, manually for the time, and i want to make sure that the `inactive` field contains a value of `active` change.

Ideally, i would like to check to see if `active=0` and place a datetime stamp, using `now()`, in the field for the record.  Long-term im sure i will want to validate that the `inactive` field doesnt have a datetime stamp already, but for now overriding it fine.  As well, would like to have it check if `active=1` and clear out the `inactive` field if any value exists.

The `inactive` field is `nullable` so there wont be a conflict.

#### Trigger Definition, as of now:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.TRG_tblRegistration_Inactive
ON dbo.tblRegistration
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    
    IF update(active) BEGIN
        
        update r
        set inactive=now()
        from tblRegistration r
            join inserted i on r.id = i.id
        where i.active = 0

    END
END
```

I have a pretty good understanding of the `inserted` & `deleted` trigger tables.

#### Question:

1. Is there a better logic pattern within the trigger that will get me the ultimate desired goal?
2. Any considerations to be had if they submit a `inactive` value with the `active=0`, or `active=1`?

#### Current Form of the Trigger:

```
ALTER TRIGGER dbo.TRG_tblRegistration_Inactive
ON dbo.tblRegistration
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    
    IF update(active) BEGIN
        update r
        set inactive=getdate()
        from tblRegistration r
            join inserted i on r.id = i.id
        where i.active = 0
        
        update r
        set inactive=NULL
        from tblRegistration r
            join inserted i on r.id = i.id
        where i.active=1
    END
END
```

It works and does as expected but want to make sure that first there isnt a better way of doing this (at the database side or in the trigger).

Comment: You can also just use the inactive flag. Instead of updating active=0, just update inactive=now() instead. That way you can get rid of the trigger altogether and the active flag. Not sure if that's an option for you however.

Comment: I personally do not like triggers too much.... I avoid them whenever possible.

Comment: @samyi i wasnt going to change the value of `active` just the `inactive` value.  I am only doing this cause the product i am developing needs to be supportive of the local IT.  I am doing the trigger as a safe guard against IT rollover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it'd be better to change `active` to a (persisted) computed column, with this definition:

```
CASE WHEN inactive IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

Then you don't need any triggers at all, and you can just set `inactive = GETDATE()` to accomplish the purpose.

Nonetheless, the way that your trigger is currently written (in both versions), the `inactive` column is going to be updated to the current date even if I run a query like this:

```
UPDATE tblRegistration
SET active = 0
WHERE active = 0
```

If you only want the date to be updated *if the field changes from 1 to 0,* then your update statement in the trigger would need to be:

```
UPDATE tblRegistration
SET inactive = GETDATE()
FROM inserted i
INNER JOIN deleted d ON i.id = d.id
WHERE tblRegistration.id = i.id AND i.active = 0 AND d.active = 1
```

Comment: So why compute based off a DateTime field?  The table has potentially 100,000 record entry, with maybe .5% of that being actively managed.  Wouldn't it be better to do a validation off a 1 bit field vs an 8 byte field?  For me, with the [inactive] field being a non-entry, that is one less value i have to give the developers to mess up, logically ;)

Comment: You can set the column as persisted, and it'll behave (performance-wise) exactly as if it were a standard column. It also guarantees the integrity of your data and forces your developers into a good habit - set the `inactive` date to mark the row as inactive, and clear it to mark it active. You still only have 1 value to update, and it avoids using a trigger (which is slower).